# adding a default option when using ng-options in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

I m having a dropdown for which I am using the `ng-options` to load the values from the model which is populated by the controller. Now I need to have one more option which is `<option value='any'>any</option>` which should be there as the selected option by default. How to do this in angular way?

```
<body ng-controller="myController">
  <h1>States in India!</h1>
  <select ng-options="state for state in states" ng-model="selectedState">      </select>
</body>
```

Plnkr link attached - [Plnkr link](http://plnkr.co/edit/3astKKW7wclW4o3fThWg?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

@Pradeep, use

```
    <select ng-options="state for state in states" ng-model="selectedState">
        <option value="">-- choose state --</option>
    </select>
```

[plunkr link](http://plnkr.co/edit/zFPkBOo3hq4QEHqtCwDw?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add one more item in array and assing it to $scope.selected. [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ebEqVZle7FZKWyPzu2kH?p=preview).

```
$scope.selectedState = "Select";
$scope.states=["Select","Karnataka", "Tamilnadu", "Andra-Pradesh", "Rajasthan"]
```

Answer (score 0):

write `option` tag inside the `select` tag like

```
  <body ng-controller="myController">
    <h1>States in India!</h1>
    <select  ng-options="state as state for state in states" ng-model="selectedState">
         <option value=''>any</option>
    </select>
  </body>


angular.module("myApp", []).

    controller("myController", function($scope){
      $scope.states=["Karnataka", "Tamilnadu", "Andra-Pradesh", "Rajasthan"]  
    })
```

I have run in plunker its work please try this

Comment: `<select ng-options="sta.planStatus as sta.planStatus for sta in status" ng-model="plan.planStatus" >
<option value="">Select Status</option>     
    </select>`